# How to fill a column with data in access table via macro

Tags: ms-access, dao, create-table

I'd like to complete the column with concatenate from other columns in the same table but I get errors. My code is as per below:

```
Dim tbl2 As DAO.TableDef
Dim db2 As DAO.Database    
Dim fld2 As DAO.Field

Set db2 = CurrentDb
Set tbl2 = db2.TableDefs("Table")

With tbl2    
    Set fld2 = tbl2.CreateField("Concatenate", dbText)    
    .Fields.Append fld2

    '*and below is the part when I get errors on both options:*
    fld2.Expression = "Account" & "-" & "Name" '<-- I get an error "Method or data member not found
    fld2.Attributes = "Account" & "-" & "Name" '<-- when I change to this I get an error "Type mismatch"

End With

Set fld2 = Nothing
Set tbl2 = Nothing
Set db2 = Nothing
```

Actually the code works, field is created properly as text, but it doesn't want to complete with values.

Could you help? How to change the code? Both options are wrong !

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
fld2.Expression = "[Account]-[Name]"
```